# Using ellipsis (omission) with verbs?

Tags: phrases, verbs, ellipses

I want to know if a sentence like this is possible: "After leaving school, John became a barrister, Alex a judge and Mark a writer." In the last two instances, "became" is omitted to avoid unsightly repetition. But it is grammatically correct to omit verbs in cases like these? Most of the examples I can find online deal with parallel constructions rather than list-like examples like these.

Any help much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The sentence is totally swell!

Comment: Grammatically correct, but it is unrealistic to say that someone leaves school to becomes a judge – that would happen much later in someone's career.

Comment: This is correct and uses good quality sentence construction. Another point of contention is whether to use an Oxford comma. :)

Comment: @WeatherVane It may be true that one does not leave school *to* (not that the sentence used the word) become  a judge but it is nevertheless true that after leaving school (during the period that started when he left school) he (at some time in that period) became a judge.

Comment: @Anton that is pedantic: there is no context where it makes sense, except from the point of view of a very young person who has no idea what happens after leaving school. One does not become a judge after leaving school: one studies law.

Comment: No problem with the sentence. It's an example of [Conjunction Reduction](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96193/15299), a very common English grammar rule.

Comment: @KannE what is SC?

Comment: Sorry, never heard of that place - not in my jurisdiction :-) My next cases are for pedantry.

Comment: @JohnLawler: It seems to me we can "delete" repeated instances of just about any linguistic elements in such contexts, ***apart from articles / determiners***. So it's not idiomatically valid to delete repeated instances of ***a*** in the cited context. Is that really a general principle, and if so might there be any kind of rationale for it?

Comment: @WeatherVane I can understand your viewpoint, but my own is not pedantic; it is merely to do with the proper use of prepositions (before, when, after, during etc) that relate to time. "After I left school I became a student, a physicist, an environmental scientist, a civil servant and a pensioner." Everything happened in the period that started when I left school. I did not leave *to* do these things.

Comment: @Anton I suggest you research the uses of 'to'. It does not always mean "for the purpose of."

Comment: @WeatherVane We have come to the point where the comma after school is conditioning a trivial debate that should be moved to chat. Thanks

Comment: @KannE she has a degree though, so plainly she did not step from school to judge.

Comment: @KannE unusual though, as even the youngest ever took a lot longer than 1 year. My [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553151/using-ellipsis-omission-with-verbs?noredirect=1#comment1362214_553151) stands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gapping comma in a list](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/510798/gapping-comma-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

> After leaving school, John became a barrister, Alex a judge and Mark a
> writer.

I'm not sure why people are answering in the comments. I will give an actual answer.

The sentence is **grammatically** perfect.

It is very odd with regard to **meaning**.  Of course they became these things *after* leaving school. They could not have done it beforehand! That makes the first clause completely redundant.

Comment: Possibly because this has been covered before.

Comment: After he asked the question, one had a criticism, one a comment and one an answer.